# How to load Jquery.js if not already loaded ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if I need to load JQuery OR it is already loaded by another page !?

How can I check this on client side ?
I want to have something like this:

```
<script >
 if jquery-1.6.2.js isExist then
   {return}
 else // somehow 
   load (<script src="../js/jq/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script> )
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This example from modernizr trays to load jquery from the google cdn if it fails it loads local jquery. Your code may be similar.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

Comment: You should only add the second line, first was just part of the example.

Comment: In my case the browser ignored the escaping with `\x3C` for the `</script>` inside the quotes. I used this instead: `document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))`

Answer (score 5):

```
<div id="loader"></div>
<script>
if (!window.jQuery) {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = '../js/jq/jquery-1.6.2.js';
    document.getElementById('loader').appendChild(e);
}
</script>
```

Comment: First we check jQuery exsist. If not exsist, we create `<script>` node and setup attributes (async and src), and attach to `#loader` div. This div after what will become `<div id="loader"><script src="../js/jq/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script></div>`

Comment: Well it doesn't work when I directly call the page. which means that IF is not working ?!!

Comment: Do you add `<div id="loader"></div>`?

Comment: I checked, my code works. Other code works too, and maybe it is a bit faster, but I like DOM :)